# Can phone apps edit my clipboard?

Tags: malware, android, ios, financial, clipboard

This is a question similar to this one but it is all about **editing** the clipboard contents.
[Can phone apps read my clipboard?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/176373/can-phone-apps-read-my-clipboard)

Is this actually a case on latest API of Android an iOS? I mean particularly  Clipper malware that e.g. replaces financial account number after it get's copied to the clipboard so then you paste attackers account number.

I digged through the documentation and some books and found information in the book that on android both read/write seems not limited, on iOS it works in foreground only. **Did not manage to confirm this information it in the docs online.**

1. So how it is currently on Android?
2. So how it is currently on iOS?
3. Is using "Share" and app drawer on android to pass the data we want to be integral from one app to another safer than using clipboard in any way(we assume you don't choose copy to clipboard in app drawer)? Is this a mitigation in case in fact there is global permission for reading/writing the clipboard and some malware wants to replace the account number that user wants to copy from the banking app and send to someone?
4. Are you aware of any Google's movements to make it more secure in those terms?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, you've clearly done the research and found that _yes_, it's possible (at least on Android). The share API on Android does not expose your data to an app until you've tapped it, so that would be safer.

Comment: @Jenessa I don't think so. At least chrome allows clipboard access for websites. Also I believe there was some clipper malware detected.